# configure HTTPS server on a cisco router

Tags: cisco, router, https

For the past week I was trying to configure an HTTPS server on a cisco 2900 router, I've used the following commands and assigned a username and password to privilege 15 however, when Im trying to access a given ip it requires a username and password however when I insert the username and password I configured it does not allow me to enter and i'm not sure where the problem is.

*Router(config)# ip http secure-server*

*Router(config)# ip http authentication local*

These were the commands i used for the https server and also I used the following to assign the username and password

*Router(config)#username name privilege 15 secret 0 password*

where 'name' and 'password' represent the username and password respectively

I'm trying to access the 192.168.14.1 interface on the router and the username and password i created are not authorized to enter

(I got the commands from a cisco router manual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be all you need; I can login to my switches via https and cisco/mysecretpassword when I use the config below.  If I had to guess, you're probably missing the `aaa` family of commands.

```
aaa new-model
aaa authentication login default local
username cisco secret mysecretpassword
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
```

Comment: basically what I did was not use the authentication local command and it was fine..although I thought of using the triple a model for the authentication, but i shall try to use the triple a model and see if that resolves the need of a username and password! anyways thank you :D